# clang-cl vs new msvc preprocessor

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio, cl, clang-cl

I wrote C11 code with heavy macro magic.

MSVC has new preprocessor mode, enabled with [/Zc:preprocessor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zc-preprocessor?view=msvc-170) . This mode is perfectly compatible with GCC and Clang preprocessor, so it does macro magic well.

But I want to use [expression block](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html) language extensions as well, which is perfectly supported by `clang-cl.exe`.

Unfortunatelly, `clang-cl.exe` immitates old `cl.exe` preprocessor, and I found no way to switch it to clang native preprocessor or `cl.exe /Zc:preprocessor` compatible mode.

For example, following code:

- compiled well with clang/gcc (unix or mingw)
- preprocessed right with `cl.exe /Zc:preprocessor`, but could not be compilled due to "expression block"
- not preprocessed right with `clang-cl.exe` (since it immitates cl.exe without new flag), therefore not compilled.

```c
static inline int func(int x) { return x; }
#define get1(...) get1_(__VA_ARGS__)
#define get1_(x, ...) x
#define call(a) ({func(a);})

int main(void)
{
    return call(get1(3,4));
}
```

Could someone suggest the way to convince `clang-cl.exe` to do preprocessing right?

Comment: Showing a [mre] might help to understand what you want.

Comment: @Bodo , I've added example.

Comment: Why would you need gcc extensions for `({func(a);})` or was this just a poor example?

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica , yes, that is why I want to use clang-cl, which perfectly understands statement expressions.

Comment: @Lundin statement expressions allows to create useful typesafe macros. It is very versatile tool.

Comment: Yes, I realized I misread. I should point out though that the post's language does require a re-read.

Comment: You shouldn't use these for type safety purposes but to implement multi-line function-like macros in the rare case where an inline function cannot be used. For type safety there's standard `_Generic` and soon to be standard `typeof`.

Comment: @Lundin, certainly I use statement expressions for multi-line function-like macros as well. Also _Generic is too restrictive to be very useful. I know why I use statement expressions, you don't need to tell me what they are useful for.